# Looking for an 80's/90's animated fantasy movie with a unicorn

Tags: identify-this-movie, fantasy

I remember watching a traditionally animated movie maybe 15-20 years ago on a VHS my parents made by recording TV. I think it may have been a series of short fairy tale segments, although I can't be sure I'm not just remembering multiple movies recorded on one tape.

One scene stands out strongly in my mind: it's nighttime, the sky is dark blue, and there's a woman in a diaphanous robe sitting in a (roofless?) gazebo with Greek marble columns. I'm pretty sure she was a unicorn, but she'd taken on human form. I have vague memories of her being separated from someone she loved. There might have been a V/O of the text of a letter she sent him, or maybe her lover was there, and they were saying goodbye? There was definitely dialogue happening. Either way, the scene was very wistful, and I've never forgotten the music that was playing in the background. It was very emotive and bittersweet. After watching the movie, I immediately ran to the piano and learned to play the tune. I can still sing it, if that helps at all.

I'm running on the assumption that it was made in the 80's or 90's (before 1998 for sure), but my memories are foggy and it could have been an older Soviet piece. The movie that was recorded after it on the VHS was a dubbed [Soviet adaptation of *The Wild Swans*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Wild_Swans_(film)).

P.S. - It's not The Last Unicorn.

Comment: I can't quite place the exact on you're talking about, but here's a list of modern movies and books with Unicorns in them. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_unicorns Hope this helps

Comment: The never ending story?

Comment: If you could play/record/upload someone could poss recognize tune. The rest of the question is good enough it won't be an "identify this tune" question.

Comment: Wow. I was reading all through your question thinking "It's The Last Unicorn, it's The Last Unicorn." Then I get to the end. Hmmm....

Comment: Bit of a wild guess, but there's a woman in a robe and lots of deep blue sky and singing in the humpback horse (Russian title), The Magic Poney - English version.    The movie is currently available in full on Youtube.   No unicorn, but it's just a guess.

Comment: Had trouble posting links last night but  Video  https://youtu.be/f0m-0bvap5A  Possibly the song and woman in dress:   https://youtu.be/m3WM1xxh2rY and IMBD:  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0290738/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1   It was originally Russian, dubbed with English.

Answer (score 3):

Unico is a unicorn character in [three animated films](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unico), which feature [a woman in a diaphanous robe](http://image.prntscr.com/image/1f907177c6b146d8ac63248ad6846160.png) as one of the main characters.

- Unico: Black Cloud and White Feather (1979 Japan)
- The Fantastic Adventures of Unico (1981 Japan/1983 USA)
- Unico in the Island of Magic (1983 Japan/1983 USA)

The first film (Unico: Black Cloud and White Feather) was a straight-to-video TV-pilot film, intended as a proposal for an animated TV series, but it never got picked up for TV. Instead, the [manga] property was adapted for the silver screen, for two more anime films.